# why is my CSS animation not working in firefox?

Tags: css

So i made this css code to test the use of css animations with variables in order to apply them in many things (i.e font color, gradients, backgrounds). The code works well in any browser but firefox, does anyone know how can i fix it?

```
:root {
    --color: 0, 0, 0;
-webkit-animation: rainbow 5s infinite;
-moz-animation: rainbow 5s infinite;
-ms-animation: rainbow 5s infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 5s infinite;
animation: rainbow 5s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes rainbow{
0%{--color: 255, 0, 0;}
1%{--color: 255, 26, 0;}
2%{--color: 255, 51, 0;}
3%{--color: 255, 77, 0;}
4%{--color: 255, 102, 0;}
5%{--color: 255, 128, 0;}
6%{--color: 255, 153, 0;}
7%{--color: 255, 179, 0;}
8%{--color: 255, 204, 0;}
9%{--color: 255, 230, 0;}
10%{--color: 255, 255, 0;}
...
}

@keyframes rainbow{
0%{--color: 255, 0, 0;}
1%{--color: 255, 26, 0;}
2%{--color: 255, 51, 0;}
3%{--color: 255, 77, 0;}
4%{--color: 255, 102, 0;}
5%{--color: 255, 128, 0;}
6%{--color: 255, 153, 0;}
7%{--color: 255, 179, 0;}
8%{--color: 255, 204, 0;}
9%{--color: 255, 230, 0;}
10%{--color: 255, 255, 0;}
...
}
```

Comment: Firefox (and Safari) requires you set the property using the animated css variable inside the animation.

Comment: There is no need of css browser prefixes anymore, unless really targetting 10+ versions oldest browsers.

Comment: @Kaiido and... how do i do that? sorry but im new to this -.-'